# using get_metric_statistics in simple_aws using ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I am trying to explore the simple_aws gem. When I connect to cloudwatch to get the metric statistics I get an error as follows:

```
cw.get_metric_statistics(
 :metric_name => metric_name,
 :period => period,
 :start_time => start_time,
 :end_time => end_time,
 :statistics => "Average",
 :namespace => "AWS/EC2"
)
```

---

```
SimpleAWS::UnsuccessfulResponse: MissingParameter (400):

   The parameter Namespace is required.
   The parameter MetricName is required.  
   The parameter StartTime is required.  
   The parameter EndTime is required.  
   The parameter Period is required.  
   The parameter Statistics is required.
```

Later, I tried this:

```
cw.get_metric_statistics(
options => [
  {:metric_name=>"CPUUtilization",
   :period=>60,
   :start_time => Time.now()-86400,
   :end_time => Time.now()-3600,
   :statistics => "Average"
  }
]
)
```

But got the following error:

```
URI::InvalidComponentError: bad component(expected query component): 

Action=GetMetricStatistics&{:metric_name=>"CPUUtilization"}.1.metric_name=CPUUtilization&{:metric_name=>"CPUUtilization"}.1.period=60&{:metric_name=>"CPUUtilization"}.1.start_time=2012-05-06%2014%3A25%3A28%20%2B0530&{:metric_name=>"CPUUtilization"}.1.end_time=2012-05-07%2013%3A25%3A28%20%2B0530&{:metric_name=>"CPUUtilization"}.1.statistics=Average&AWSAccessKeyId=AccessKey&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2012-05-07T08%3A55%3A28Z&Version=2010-08-01&Signature=Signature
```

one more try:

```
cw.get_metric_statistics(
namespace: 'AWS/EC2',
measure_name: 'CPUUtilization',
statistics: 'Average',
start_time: time-1000,
dimensions: "InstanceId=#{instance_id}"
```

### )

ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed

Can anybody please help find the correct syntax for issuing this command.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = cw.get_metric_statistics(step,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      metric,
      'AWS/RDS',
      'Average',
      dimensions={'DBInstanceIdentifier': [indentifier]})
```

This also worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works;

```
lat = cw.get_metric_statistics(
  'MetricName' => 'Latency',
  'Period' => 60,
  'StartTime' => (Time.now() - 3600).iso8601,
  'EndTime' => Time.now().iso8601,
  'Statistics.member.1' => "Average",
  'Namespace' => "AWS/ELB",
  'Unit' => 'Seconds'
)
```

Firstly that the datetime is required in ISO8601 format, secondly that the parameters need to be cased correctly, thirdly the Unit parameter is required, and finally that Statistics needed a namespace(?) after it.

Hope this helps, even if it is a little late.